# UnrealEngine can't start packaged game for Windows

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm trying to create build of default unreal engine editor game example. I keep project structure/settings/package settings and everything else untouched.

Steps i do:

1. Created new project in Unreal Engine Editor, (first character
   project with started content)
2. Name it "BuildTest"
3. Tried to create build for windows x64. File -> Package Project -> Windows -> Windows (64 bit)
4. Choose desktop folder to save project
5. Close unreal editor as well as epic launcher (tried not to close these tools as well)
6. Open desktop folder WindowsNoEditor
7. Run BuildTest.exe

After that nothing happens, i see new process in windows tasks list but no any new windows appears.

BTW i can't kill that process, only reboot make me able to remove that indowsNoEditor folder. Have tried to close that process using CMD -> taskkill /im BuildTest.exe /t /f

If you had similar experience, any help appreciated, ready to provide packaging logs.

System info:

- Windows 7, original latest updates installed.
- Unreal Engine Editor v4.10
- cpu: I7
- ram: 8gb

Comment: We don't really do *Here's a very vague thing I did. It doesn't work. Please speculate on the millions of things that could be wrong with what I did that you have no information regarding. Thanks.* type questions here.

Comment: There isn't anything obviously wrong with your process (except where you say close the editor, I assume you're waiting for the build to finish successfully?) It might be some edge case bug you've stumbled on and you'd be better off posting this on [Unreal Answers](http://answers.unrealengine.com) to get a staff members help. That said, the log for the exe is in `ProjectName/Saved/Logs/` in your build directory which might give you a clue as to what's going wrong.

Comment: @Rantiev I meant the log from the packaged exe, if the executable is appearing in your process but never showing a screen, it is more likely something is going wrong in the exe than the build. The other thing to try is delete all Saved and Intermediate directories and do a full rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I have got it eventually. If you try to build first character project or blank project with no starter content. You will most likely get my experience, that's because you try to make build of game with no levels.

If you want to try to build anything, create first character project with starter content, than you will be able to play it ouside edotir.